# tracking sharepoint log in

Tags: search

We have an issue on a sharepoint site we are running.

We have a site that is utilized for checking prices and catalogues.  Up until now we never tried checking how many persons are accessing the site.

We started investigating and found the following:
1. Despite Microsoft sharepoint "view auditing reports" Content Activity Reports and custom reports options it is impossible to generate reports for viewing content
2. Despite the many published sites with instructions and long blogs, it appears that "You cannot track retroactively who logged onto a site. Period."

So with our project we are at square 1.... or rather square 0.

So I am here askign for some answers, advice, etc.

Is retroactive tracking at all possible?

If it is possible, how?
Are there ad ons that could be utilized, or software that could simply be enabled without the need to make installations at server or user level?

Thank you in advance,

Pawel

Answer (score 0):

You cannot report on data you have not collected.  First you must turn on the auditing features in Site Settings.  Then, after a day of collection, you will be able to report on that data.  This not retroactive.

Note: SharePoint will store this data in the database with your site content.  Be prepared for database growth.

Comment: Not quite sure I agree with you.  Based on what we have seen and what MS has indicated trackign viewing/logging on is not possible.  We have tested this and log ons are not registered.  MS has indicated as part of their privacy policy they do nto retroactively track log ons.

Comment: I thought the OP said logins in the title, but the reporting was basically who has viewed the site.  Perhaps I misunderstood the question.